# Use custom authentication methods with default provided method in Ktor simultaneously

Tags: authentication, hmac, ktor, custom-authentication

I have created one custom authentication method to support HMAC authentication. Now I want to combine this method with JWT authentication that is provided as a default authentication method in Ktor.
I want to combine these in such a way that my route can be authenticated by any one of these methods.

I have tried with this

```
withSignature {
            show()
}

authenticate( "auth-jwt") {
            show()
}
```

When I am trying to access `show()` with `auth-jwt`, it is taking `withSignature` and throwing error.

I want to access the route by any authentication method, `auth-jwt` or `withSignature`.

Comment: Shouldn't the `authenticate("auth-jwt", "auth-hmac", strategy = AuthenticationStrategy.FirstSuccessful) {}` code work for you (assuming that you have the `auth-jwt` and `auth-hmac` providers)?